# A famous plaything - who am I?

Tags: riddle

A famous plaything, beloved by geeks 
If you are like many, my meaning you'll seek 
From six letters to five, I'm a journey complete 
You can play me once, but you won't get a repeat

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> Life (or one of two Games of Life)

I'm a famous game, beloved by geeks

> John Conway's Game of Life is famous and beloved by geeks

If you are like many, my meaning you'll seek

> People seek the meaning of life

From six letters to five, I'm a journey complete

> From CRADLE (6) to GRAVE (5)

You can play me once, but you won't get a repeat

> Once you die, that's it (unless you believe in reincarnation)
>  I refuse to quote Drake here.

Comment: Nice job, I had a feeling this one will go pretty fast...

Comment: For the last line I would have just put "YOLO!"